# Java download xml stored in string

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts

I have String that contains xml data like :

```
String strXml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> <Name> sample     <name> ";
```

I want to download the string strXml as XML file. Below code open the xml file instead of downloading it.

```
PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
out.write(strXml );
```

Please suggeest how to download the data in string strXml as XML file.

Comment: Downloading and copying is different.

Comment: I think you basically want to write xml string into a file.

Comment: No, I want to download file as XML that should contain the data of string strXml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are talking about file download from web site?
You should write following response headers:

```
Content-type: application/octet-stream

Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=filename.xml
```

then you can just `out.print(strXml)` with a content of the file. Browser will ask a user to download filename.xml

Answer (score 0):

Create an xml file in java and save the string there in that file..

Use try catch for proper exception handling. I hope I have not forgot the syntax, this is how that would be done.

```
 FileOutputStream outfile=new FileOutputStream (new File('newFile.xml'));
 PrintOutputStream out=new PrintOutputStream(outfile);
 String strXml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> <Name>
 sample     <name> ";

 out.print(strXml );
 out.close();
```

Comment: Or just write it to the response and avoid the overhead.

Comment: As you can see in my question i have already written to response like PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
out.write(strXml ); But it open the XML in browser instead of downloading it.

Comment: @Amritsingh yes, but you can save the response in a file..are you saving it separately or not?